# Not able to edit MsBuilds default template

Tags: msbuild, tfsbuild

I am currently working on **TFS** automated build process and I won't able to edit/create my process template using Default Template. I did all the process required to edit the Default Template, the process is specified in above link, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd647551.aspx.

When I try to edit the imported file, Encoding message box appears. If I click in "OK" in Encoding box then the template file get encoded in unexpected format and "Invalid Markup" message appears in designer view of WF.

Please suggest on this. I know it's difficult to understand the scenario without Images but I m not able to post an Image because I don't have reputation >10.

So It's really very much appreciating if someone help me on the basis of Info. I have provided.

Thanking you in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

If you're running into encoding issues, you can edit the file directly in notepad after checking it out.  Then "Save As..."  change the encoding, then save.  Then try to reopen it.  Sometimes

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have tried this thing before posting this question. However it opens in a encoded format only. So this is not the way for sure.

Comment: Are you opening the Default Template in VS 2013?  Seems to be the case.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to have solved someone else's issue:

http://enginecore.blogspot.com/2014/01/invalid-markup-in-xaml-in-visual-studio.html

- close all files open in Visual Studio
- close Visual Studio
- delete the .suo file near the .sln
- delete bin and obj folders